# AS3,AIR,Socket: How to readObject() correctly?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, bitmap, air

I'm trying to pass a bitmap from an AIR app (server) to another (client), using the **writeObject()** method from the **Socket** class.

```
clientSocket.writeObject(myBitmap);// (var myBitmap:Bitmap)
clientSocket.flush();
```

My problem appears when I try to get the bitmap, on the client app. Using the method **readObject()**, I'm obtaining a generic Object, with all properties of the bitmap. I can't convert this object to bitmap by any way.

```
var receivedObject:* = socket.readObject();
trace(receivedObject);// [Object Object]
trace(receivedObject as Bitmap); // null
```

Some help please?

This kind of process is not well documented by Adobe.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap` class is a `DisplayObject` and cloning via `ByteArray` feature (with `writeObject/readObject` methods) don't work for `DisplayObjects` (check out this question for example [how to work registerClassAlias() method for custom mxml components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576627/how-to-work-registerclassalias-method-for-custom-mxml-components)).

For this particular case you can write/read `BitmapData` object and the `Rectangle` property and restore `Bitmap` with it.

```
    var bd:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
    var data:Object = {rect:bd.rect, bytes:bd.getPixels(bd.rect)}
    clientSocket.writeObject(data);

    var data:Object = socket.readObject();
    var bd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(data.rect.width, data.rect.height);
    bd2.setPixels(bd2.rect, data.bytes);
    addChild(new Bitmap(bd2));
```